# Which uniform is this?

Tags: identification, uniform

[image: Uniformed soldier with four chevrons on lower sleeve, wearing a forage cap]

May be my Great Great Grandfather Peter or Edward Hepburn.  We do not know anything about him. Is it from the Crimea? What rank and/or regiment?  My cousin said her father told her it might have been Crimean war and from Scotland.

Comment: Including an photo or two would help. Why do you think it is from the Crimean War?

Answer (score 2):

The cap is an officers pattern 1880 forage cap which was used until around 1902. The white band as I understand it represents an English or Welsh regiment and the grenade on his cuff above the stripes might suggest one of the fusilier regiments.
The rank is possibly a regimental quartermaster sergeant though I don't know what the two extra stars represent.

Comment: So this is a generation (or possibly two) after the Crimean War?

Comment: He was born 1833

Comment: If he was born in 1833 then that would mesh with the photo being late 19th century as he looks to be in his 60s. He may well have served in the Crimean War as he would have been around 20 when it started. I do wonder at his age here as would he have purchased an up to date uniform or were men his age somehow involved with the military still.

Answer (score 0):

A post-1880 photograph of a Quartermaster-Sergeant in a Volunteer Royal Engineers unit, wearing an other-ranks patrol jacket.  The stars on cuff indicate long service in volunteer/militia forces.  The grenade is actually part of his rank insignia, and has nothing to do with any connection to any fusiliers unit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).